# Rewrite dynamic url in .htaccess?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is an example url. 
97006 is the query string.
Customer-Manager is a title that changes for every page.
jobdetails.php is run when a button is clicked which brings you to a page like this below.

http://11.11.111.111/97006/Customer-Manager.html

I would like the url to be:
http://11.11.111.111/job/Customer-Manager.html

In the .htaccess there is already code for the url I want to change.

I think this is the condition for the rule: (because its the 1st condition & 1st rule, is thst how it works?)

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]`

This is the rule I have tried changing many times but no success:
`RewriteRule ^([1-9][0-9]*)/([-.,_0-9a-zA-z]*)\.html$  job_details.php?query_string=$1&action=%1 [L]`

This code makes the url when for the button:

`$button = tep_href_link($id.'/'.$title.'.html');`

I have research apache directives, regular expressions and tried many tutorials but whenever I change anything in the htaccess for that line I get sent to the wrong url or the site crashes altogether.

Comment: http://11.11.111.111/<number>/Customer-Manager.html                                      to   http://11.11.111.111/job/Customer-Manager.html    I think Customer-Manager.html is the action

Comment: surely the 97006 is an id from the db? I guess Custom-Manager is also derived from the db? If you remove the id how would the script find the right info?

Comment: `http://11.11.111.111/<number>/<anything>` is what you possibly want?

Comment: I still want the id to be in the url in secret but just not shown to the public that way. Yes, they are both from the db. I would like to make it more seo friendly. I have been reading about alias but I'm not sure if thats whats needed.

Comment: That is the way the url is already John White. I want to allow the url to appear as     `http://11.11.111.111/job/<any job title>.html or maybe even http://11.11.111.111/<any job title>.html`

Comment: Any suggestions would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is impossible you can use this url instead :

http://example.com/jobs/97006/data.html

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /job_details.php?query_string=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Surely its possible to just keep the id in as hidden and make the url appear to be something cleaner.

Comment: how would you hide the id?

Comment: From what I have read its possible but the htaccess is tricky.

Comment: If you are suggesting that rather than use 97006 in the url you use 'job' in it's place then you would need to maintain some sort of lookup facility server side to decode what 'id' the 'job' parameter referred to - or perhaps I'm missing something here.

Comment: Ok, could you help with a similar problem? I have a search.php which has doesnt display any variables but I would like it to display 2 variables at the end. This is current url: http://11.11.111.111/search.php But I would like it to be: http://11.11.111.111/search.php?q=example&q2=example

Comment: post the code for search.php so we can see what and how and why things do or do not do what they are supposed to